# how correct use FileUpload DOTVVM

Tags: dotvvm

I have a problem with "FileUpload" control from `DOTVVM`.
My project is in `ASP Core 2 and I` use `DOTVVM`.

I added to the project:

1. Folder App_Data / Temp
2. I have added `options.AddUploadedFileStorage ("App_Data / Temp")` to the `DotvvmStartup` file in the `ConfigureServices` section;
3. In the `.dotcontrol` file I added:

```
<dot: FileUpload UploadedFiles = "{value: Files}" AllowMultipleFiles = "true" />
```

When I click the button nothing happens.

1. In the console (Firefox developer tools) an error appears:

   > TypeError: t.document.getElementById (...) is null
2. When I set breakpoint to `ConfigureServices (IDotvvmServiceCollection options)`, the program does not enter this block of code

The problem appears in version 2.0

Please help

Comment: >When I set breakpoint to ConfigureServices (IDotvvmServiceCollection options), the program does not enter this block of code

This seems that you don't register DotVVM at all. It's strange that something appears in the browser, does anything else work correctly? Is the `DotvvmStartup.Configure` method invoked?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know where was error. In the Startup file in the ConfigureServices section, I had services.AddDotVVM (); instead of services.AddDotVVM <DotvvmStartup> ();

Comment: Ahh, that's quite nasty API, sorry for that. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to avoid this nastiness in the API without breaking compatibility :(


Could you just please answer the question with this solution? Hopefully, it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I know where was error. In the Startup file in the ConfigureServices section, I had services.AddDotVVM (); instead of services.AddDotVVM  ();